# Trying to find files beggining with a number

Tags: command-line, files, find

For my school, I need to search all the files who start with a numeric. Ive tried searching on the web before but didnt find any answer. I need to use the `find` command.

The question is: Are there any files on the server that begin with a number? If yes can you list them?

The answer is yes there is (Because he want us to redirect the error 2>/dev/null)

I've been trying different things but nothing work. The closest I've been to the answer is this command line

```
find /home | grep '[0-9]'
```

To have the number first I thought I just needed to put `^` before `[0-9]` but it didn't work.

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
find . -type f -regex ".*/[0-9]*"
```

The regex is done on the whole path so you need to include the `.*/`.

```
sudo find / -type f -regex ".*/[0-9]*"
```

if you want it for the whole filesystem.

Comment: Doesn't this only find files whose names consist *wholly* of digits? Why use `-regex` here at all, in preference to `-name '[0-9]*'`?

Answer (score 0):

When looking for a pattern in Linux, often you can use a [regular expression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) (*regex*). Most unix commands dealing with search, will allow you to use them. With that in mind, you can look for the term in the manual: `man find`. The `find` command allows you to use a regex using the `-regex` flag.

To answer your specific question:

```
find . -type f -regex '.*/[0-9][^/]*$'
```

Will do the trick. But if you take a look through the manual, you will probably find other ways to achieve the same result.

Comment: Doesn't this also find files whose paths contain a directory that starts with a digit? Why use `-regex` here at all, in preference to `-name '[0-9]*'`?

Comment: You're right. The regex was changed to exclude any extra slashes in the path. I think you would need the regex exactly because of this. with `-name` you will also find paths that contain a directory that start with a digit.
But more in general, I imagine the teacher wants to learn students that in Linux there is never only one answer.

Comment: AFAIK `-name` *only* tests against the basename - I don't see how it would also find paths that contain a directory that start with a digit?

Comment: Ah, indeed. I was using `-name` without the `-type f` parameter.